# Groupby to empty df with fixed series names

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, series

I basically want to see an empty field, not necessarily "0" for the series "semi" for groupby of group1 for df1. Since group1 doesn't have 'semi' it's just not reported at all, but I would like it to be fixed.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Title': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'C13'], 
                   'Whole': ['full', 'full', 'part', 'full', 'semi']})

group1 = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']

d_group1 = df1[df1.Title.isin(group1)]

d_count_group1 = pd.Series(['full', 'part', 'semi'], dtype=str)
print(d_count_group1)

d_count_group1 = d_group1.groupby(['Whole']).agg({'Whole': ['count']})
print(d_count_group1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
d_group1.groupby('Whole')['Whole'].count()\
        .rename('count')\
        .reindex(['full', 'part', 'semi'], fill_value='-')\
        .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Whole count
0  full     2
1  part     1
2  semi     -
```